# Heatmap from DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

I have list of experiments(exp_id) in data framе and results ( output1, output2, output3) (

| exp_id | output1 | output2 | output3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| exp1 | a | b | NaN |
| exp2 | c | a | b |
| exp3 | a | NaN | d |
| exp4 | a | d | c |

I would like to create another table where the "frequency" column describes the frequency of occurrence of a pair in one experiment (row) from the previous table.
And then I need to build a Heatmap from this table where the brightness of the color indicates the frequency of occurrence of the pair [Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z71J.png)

| pair | partner1 | partner2 | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 2 |
| 2 | a | c | 2 |
| 3 | a | d | 2 |
| 4 | b | a | 2 |
| 5 | b | d | 0 |
| 6 | b | c | 1 |
| 7 | c | a | 2 |
| 8 | c | b | 1 |
| 9 | c | d | 1 |
| 10 | d | a | 2 |
| 11 | d | b | 0 |
| 12 | d | c | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe of all combinations (`q1,q2`) of each row, then use these combinations in both ways (both `q1,q2` and `q2,q1`), then count them and create a table.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877699/heatmap-from-dataframe')[0]

combos1 = pd.DataFrame([[q1, q2] for p1, p2, p3 in zip(df['output1'], df['output2'], df['output3'])
                        for q1, q2 in combinations([p1, p2, p3], 2) if not np.NaN in [q1, q2]],
                       columns=['q1', 'q2'])
combos2 = pd.DataFrame({'q1': list(combos1['q1']) + list(combos1['q2']),
                        'q2': list(combos1['q2']) + list(combos1['q1'])})
table = combos2.value_counts().reset_index(name='count').pivot('q1', 'q2', 'count')
sns.heatmap(data=table, annot=True, fmt='.0f', cmap='rocket')
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap from combinations]